# How to set Shape for particular value on line chart in jfreechart?

Tags: jfreechart, shapes

Hi i am new to jfreechart.
I want to display the shape to the  particular value on the linechart.
I used **setSeriesShapesVisible()** method , but it displays shapes for all data points.

How to draw shape for particular value in line chart?
Bz i want to draw the shapes for only max and min values in the linechart.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please give me some example for how to use `XYShapeAnnotation` class?

Yes, several example are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20XYShapeAnnotation).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [XYShapeAnnotation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html) (check the others subclasses of `AbstractXYAnnotation`, maybe there is one that suits you more). Create a new annotation, and add it to your plot with `XYPlot.addAnnotation`

Comment: Can you please give  me some example for how to use XYShapeAnnotation class?